# Electronics interface circuit for PIN Photodiode

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, photodiode, transimpedance

I am designing an interfacing circuit for `PIN` photodiode which will be used in `NIR` spectrophotometer project. The PIN diode is `IG22x250S4i` and works in `photovoltaic mode`. The specifications are:

1. Capacitance (@0V): 40pF
2. Forward Voltage: 0.56 V
3. Reverse Voltage Max: 5V
4. Forward Current: 1 mA Max
5. Reverse Current: 0.5 mA (Max)
6. Dark Current: 0.5 uA (at 5 V reverse voltage)
7. Shunt Impedance: 400 - 500 k ohm
8. Wavelength: 1150 - 2200 nm

The datasheet of the sensor is over [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/393110187/IG22X250S4i-ds). The application notes and reference circuit is over [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/393110284/IG22x250S4i).

Initially, I tried connecting a 10 k ohm resistor in parallel to the diode and observe the response in a `oscilloscope`. I was getting 500mV max when the light source is bought near to the diode. Rather, I realized that due to 50 ohm impedance of probe, I was getting much smaller signal.

Later, I picked a random `op-amp` (input bias current in 100 pA) and designed the circuit similar to the one given below (with jumper wire):

[image]

I was getting rail-to-rail signal (3.3V) with that op-amp but it was very noisy.

I have now moved to designing a `PCB` with an [opamp](https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/analog-devices-inc/AD8616ARMZ/AD8616ARMZ-ND/1971611). I have read this [document](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/optimizing-precision-photodiode-sensor-circuit-design.html) and considered selecting an opamp with `low input bias current`, low `input offset voltage`.

But I am confused with bandwidth and slew rate of the opamp for my application. My setup has a single `PIN` diode and a stepper motor. Light after passing through the sample and lens fall on `grating`. The grating splits the light and falls on the diode. The motor moves to capture the whole spectrum. The time required to capture the spectrum is 1 seconds and 3000 points will be taken in that interval. So, one sample will be around `333.3 us`. If I hypothetical consider a peak in spectrum causes an instantaneous jump of `0` V to `3.3` V (of photodiode output) in single point (out of 3000 points), then maximum rate of change of input voltage (to opamp) will be `0.0099 V/ us` and that's how i concluded the slew rate of opamp should be more than `0.0099 V/ us`.

I am not confident about my calculation and are looking for similar calculations to calculate required bandwidth of the opamp.

Comment: "I was getting rail-to-rail signal (3.3V) with that op-amp but it was very noisy."  Do you mean that it was oscillating?  Because that's generally what happens when you take an op-amp that's internally compensated and put together a circuit like that.  The photodiode has high capacitance, and op-amps don't like capacitance from \$V_-\$ to ground.  Generally you need a cap in parallel with your feedback resistance to kill the oscillation.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes it was oscillating. Can you help me with calculation of capacitor across feedback resistor when we know input capacitance?

Comment: I always do it by experimentation :( !!  I think you want \$\frac{1}{2 \pi R C}\$ to be about four times less than the GBW product of the op-amp.  That should at least be a good starting point.  There's ways to make the circuit faster -- see the [LTC6244 data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6244fb.pdf) for detail, although don't think for a second that you have to use that particular amp.

Comment: @TimWescott Are my slew rate calculations right?

Comment: Your slew rate calculations look good.