# Schematics of PIN Photodiode interfacing with an ADC

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb, circuit-design, schematics, photodiode

This question is in continuation of my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/406574/electronics-interface-circuit-for-pin-photodiode).

I am moving forward with PCB designing now. I have selected low input-bias current op-amp [AD8616](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8615_8616_8618.pdf) for converting current signal into voltage. I have used another AD8616 op-amp as a buffer. I am using internal ADC of my microcontroller (`PIC24EP256GP204`).

The PIN diode is `IG22x250S4i` and works in `photovoltaic mode`. The specifications are:

1. Capacitance (@0V): 40pF
2. Forward Voltage: 0.56 V
3. Reverse Voltage Max: 5V
4. Forward Current: 1 mA Max
5. Reverse Current: 0.5 mA (Max)
6. Dark Current: 0.5 uA (at 5 V reverse voltage)
7. Shunt Impedance: 400 - 500 k ohm
8. Wavelength: 1150 - 2200 nm

The datasheet of the sensor is over [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/393110187/IG22X250S4i-ds). The application notes and reference circuit is over [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/393110284/IG22x250S4i).

The schematics is given below:

[image]

My questions are:

1. What can I do with ground/case pin of PIN photodiode to improve performance? Currently, I have just grounded it.
2. I am using second op-amp as buffer. Is there any possibility of buffer getting unstable? What measures I can take?
3. I am included a capacitor in parallel with feedback resistor to compensate the pole included by capacitance of PIN diode. What other measures I can take to stabilize my interface circuit if I found any instability after I get my PCB done?

Comment: um, correct me, but this is a bit hazardously defined for a *current* amplifier (calculte the input impedance of the first stage!): The Analog datasheet respects that by not using the photodiode in photovoltaic, but in photoconductive mode.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have updated my question with links of datasheet of PIN diode. Actually, in the datasheet, they have mentioned to use photovoltaic mode.

Comment: Honest, friendly-meant question: Did you understand my previous comment? So, your circuit is the wrong choice.

Comment: Can you elaborate? My previous question is over here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/406574/electronics-interface-circuit-for-pin-photodiode . Have a look at the Amplification circuit given in the application note as well in my previous question.

Comment: I elaborated on that in the first comment. Your opamp circuit is not a current amplifier. You need a current amplifier when operating in photovoltaic mode.

Comment: I think I have been trying to do `transimpedance amplification`. The datasheet says the voltage across the diode should be 0V for low dark current. I have selected the op-amp with very low input-bias current and all of the current through PIN photodiode will flow through feedback resistor, thus converting current into voltage and virtual short-circuit of both inputs will keep the PIN diode at 0V bias. I have limited knowledge. Please correct me if I am wrong and show me the path a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86476/discussion-between-abhiarora-and-marcus-muller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what Marcus Muller says, your circuit will work, as far as it goes. The circuit you show is not, in fact a current amplifier, but you don't want a current amplifier, so the question is moot. What you want is a current-to-voltage converter, and that's what you've got.

> 1 What can I do with ground/case pin of PIN photodiode to improve
>   performance? Currently, I have just grounded it.

That is about all you can do.

> 2 I am using second op-amp as buffer. Is there any possibility of buffer
>   getting unstable? What measures I can take?

Look at pages 11 and 12 of the data sheet. The AD8616 is unity-gain stable, which means that for most loads you don't need to take any special measures. An ADC does not normally have what is called a high-capacitance input.

> 3 I am included a capacitor in parallel with feedback resistor to
>   compensate the pole included by capacitance of PIN diode. What other
>   measures I can take to stabilize my interface circuit if I found any
>   instability after I get my PCB done?

The most important thing you can do is done before you get the PCB made. Provide decoupling and a ground plane. Decoupling is done with a 0.1 to 1 uF ceramic capacitor (not a disk cap) from Vcc to ground as close to the power pin as you can put it. For a relatively high-speed op amp like the AD8616 and low signal levels, a ground plane is a must.

I suggest that, once you have a pcb, tune the feedback cap. Modulate an LED with a square wave at about 1 kHz, shine it on your grating, move the grating until the detector is illuminated, and observe the op amp output. With a good square wave generator and a non-white LED you should be able to get optical rise and fall times below 1 usec. Look at the rising and falling edges with a scope set to about 1 to 10 usec/div. If the op amp is oscillating, or the rise/fall edges ring, increase the cap. If the edges are slow and don't settle quickly to final value, decrease the cap. In this way you can optimize your response.

If the optimized response is too slow, about the only thing you can try is to provide a bias voltage. Instead of tieing the PD anode to ground, connect it to a negative voltage of something like -5 volts. You will then be able to reduce the feedback cap and get quicker response. If you've designed your board with only positive voltages, like a single 3.3, you're just out of luck. Keep this in mind when you design the board.

If you don't want to provide a ground plane because of cost, fine. It's your choice, but performance may suffer, depending on how good you are at layout.

As you may have realized, it's a good idea to put the op amp as close to the detector as possible, as well as the summing-junction side of the feedback components, as close to the - input of the op amp as possible, in order to minimize total input capacitance.

Comment: To improve performance, Should I go with current amplification stage and then current-to-voltage converter circuit? Can you differentiate two approaches?

Comment: @abhiarora - Sorry, but "current amplifiers" don't work the way you seem to think they do. There are tricks you can do, like cascode inputs, which will improve the noise performance, but you are pretty much stuck as far as speed is concerned. The obvious approach is to improve the optics so that you get more light on the detector and can decrease the gain.